# Drawing/sampling with replacement (Probability/Combinatorics)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have an urn with $w$ white marbles and $b$ black marbles and we draw $n$ marbles with replacement. We want to know the probability of drawing $k$ white marbles ($k<n$) and apparently we use the following formula:

$$\frac{\binom{n}{k}w^kb^{n - k}}{(w + b)^n}$$

What is the logic/intuition behind it?

Comment: The formula is essentially that of the binomial distribution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: A bit late...but thank you! :)